# How do I trigger an event after a certain amount of scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this little code and it's working fine for my header img. But later on my page I want to use the same effect again. Except the action is called from the first moment I begin to scroll. So I want the action to happen when I'm at the relevant div, or after a certain amount of pixels. What do I need to add?

Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
    $('.blur_img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried 'delay' and something with scrollTop, but it makes it difficult that english isn't my native language so I'm not sure what's the most effective way to ask Google ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a check in your code:

.scrolltop() returns how much the user has scrolled vertically.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (s > 200) {
        opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
        $('.blur_img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found [viewport.js](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) very useful to detect scrolling.

> Viewport adds a couple of extra selectors to jQuery.
>   With these selectors you can check whether element is 
>   inside or outside of viewport.

So when the element later in your page enters the "viewport" your function can be called to load more content, or whatever other action you need to do.